# Getting XAException while committing the transaction, J2CA0027E - The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '106' & '-4''

Tags: java, spring, websphere, ibm-mq

I've one application in which I'm trying to process a file which contains 500k transactions, the processing of file completes in 3 minutes and the timeout is set to 15 minutes, still getting timeout exception during commit.

Getting Below Exception in Websphere System Logs while committing the transaction from my code in spring, due to which all the transactions are rolledback;

```
XATransaction E J2CA0027E: An exception occurred while invoking end on an XA Resource Adapter from DataSource JMS$FundtechQConFactory$JMSManagedConnection@75, within transaction ID {​​​XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54),
data(0000017bdaabecde0000000b6a6fc584d5dba62aea917f1902693232b82dd8a4ff309f370000017bdaabecde0000000b6a6fc584d5dba62aea917f1902693232b82dd8a4ff309f37000000010000000000000000000000000097)}​​​ : javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_end' has failed with errorCode '106'.
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.end(JmqiXAResource.java:559)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSXAResource.end(JMSManagedSession.java:1410)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.end(XATransactionWrapper.java:623)
at com.ibm.ws.Transaction.JTA.JTAResourceBase.end(JTAResourceBase.java:254)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.sendEnd(RegisteredResources.java:1154)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeEnd(RegisteredResources.java:1130)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.distributeEnd(TransactionImpl.java:1748)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.prepareResources(TransactionImpl.java:1478)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TransactionImpl.stage1CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:630)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1040)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:974)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:307)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1035)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)




XATransaction E J2CA0027E: An exception occurred while invoking rollback on an XA Resource Adapter from DataSource JMS$FundtechQConFactory$JMSManagedConnection@206, within transaction ID {​​​XidImpl: formatId(57415344), gtrid_length(36), bqual_length(54),
data(0000017bdaabecde0000000b6a6fc584d5dba62aea917f1902693232b82dd8a4ff309f370000017bdaabecde0000000b6a6fc584d5dba62aea917f1902693232b82dd8a4ff309f37000000010000000000000000000000000003)}​​​ : javax.transaction.xa.XAException: The method 'xa_rollback' has failed with errorCode '-4'.
at com.ibm.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource.rollback(JmqiXAResource.java:874)
at com.ibm.ejs.jms.JMSManagedSession$JMSXAResource.rollback(JMSManagedSession.java:1201)
at com.ibm.ejs.j2c.XATransactionWrapper.rollback(XATransactionWrapper.java:1328)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.JTAXAResourceImpl.rollback(JTAXAResourceImpl.java:381)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.deliverOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:1718)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeOutcome(RegisteredResources.java:2004)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.RegisteredResources.distributeRollback(RegisteredResources.java:2657)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1973)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.internalRollback(TransactionImpl.java:1936)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.coreStage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1156)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.stage2CommitProcessing(TransactionImpl.java:1183)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.processCommit(TransactionImpl.java:1044)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:974)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.TranManagerImpl.commit(TranManagerImpl.java:439)
at com.ibm.tx.jta.impl.TranManagerSet.commit(TranManagerSet.java:191)
at com.ibm.ws.tx.jta.UserTransactionImpl.commit(UserTransactionImpl.java:307)
at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1035)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
```

Comment: Which timeout is set to 15 minutes?

Comment: JTA timeout....

Comment: Are you using WebSphere App Server Transaction manager or internal Spring? Where did you set that timeout?

Comment: WebSphere Platform 9.0.5.5  and IBM MQ

Answer (score 1):

Error code [106](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.transaction.xa.XAException.XA_RBTIMEOUT) that you get on xa.end is [XA_RBTIMEOUT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAException.html#XA_RBTIMEOUT).
This means that the resource manager has rolled back the transaction due to exceeding a timeout.

Error code [-4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#javax.transaction.xa.XAException.XAER_NOTA) that you get on xa.commit is [XAER_NOTA](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/transaction/xa/XAException.html#XAER_NOTA).
This means that the transaction xid isn't valid anymore, which makes sense given the previous error - because transaction branch was already rolled back due to the timeout.

It is important to be aware that transaction timeouts can be set at various levels. WebSphere Application Server has a [global transaction lifetime timeout](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was/8.5.5?topic=server-transaction-service-settings). Various resource providers will often have their own timeout settings (I'd recommend checking if MQ does) which can cause them to time out their transaction branches prior to the overall transaction. Applications can specify a transaction timeout on [UserTransaction](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html#setTransactionTimeout-int-), although it appears in this case you are going through Spring, which might be specifying that value, so also look into Springs settings for transaction timeout.